# c# async await threading- how it work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

There is some function that should by `async` like `CopyToAsync`/`WriteAsync`/`ReadAsync` .

I can do `await` on them and my thread continue to work on another code, and when those function will end, they will notify me.
They do not waste CPU time and I do not need to open another thread for them.

But, when I want to do some `async` job that i don't have a function for this, like delete file.

I can wrap this function like:

```
public static class FileExtensions {
   public static Task DeleteAsync(this FileInfo fi) {
      return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fi.Delete() );
   }
}
```

and call to this function like:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
await fi.DeleteAsync();
```

what I want to know is:

1 - what will happen when I do this wrapper?
This will open new thread for this(from the `ThreadPool`) that waste CPU time while it wait for this function?
What is the different between really `async` function and this wrapper?

2 - How can I know if the function that I use on C# is really `async` function until the kernel?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _waste cpu time_, but a synchronous IO call doesn't cause the CPU to work any harder, it just blocks the thread from doing other work.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html to clarify "What is the different between really async function and this wrapper?".

Comment: @juharr 
that what i mean , if my thread not do anything i call wast cpu time

when i do CopyToAsync so while the system copy the file my thread do another things..

Comment: @Evk
that not help me, i understand that when i do wait for realy async function there i no another thread.
but when i do wait on warpper function what will do, what is the different?   
Task.Run will open a new thead , so what i get when i wrapper the delete on async await  ?

Comment: @FADI1987 a blocked thread is not the same as the CPU being blocked.  It just means the thread is in a wait queue and the CPU is able to work on other threads.  The reason to avoid blocking threads is the overhead of needing more threads to do additional work.  But if you need to not block the UI thread then pushing that work onto a background thread that does get blocked is definitely better.

Comment: Well you are doing this (wrapping Delete in async), so I suppose you have some reasoning. You get what you get - delete is run on background thread-pool thread. Whether you have any benefit from it or not - you should know better for your particular situation. In most cases there is no benefit in doing that.

Comment: @Evk
why you dont know if i have benefit from wrap this function?
what is the alternative way?

Comment: Alternative way is just call `fi.Delete()` and done. If you need to perform many deletes and you are on UI thread which you don't want to block - put all deletes in one `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Evk   I want to scan a list of directories and delete all files that over then 100 kb how can i do all the delete on 1 task.run? (and if i get it when the delete happen the process will still scan the directory)

Answer (score 3):

First, your wrapper should use `Task.Run` and not `StartNew`. [`StartNew` is a dangerous, low-level API](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), and you should not use it.

> what will happen when I do this wrapper?

It'll run the delete-file operation on a thread pool thread.

> This will open new thread for this(from the ThreadPool) that waste CPU time while it wait for this function?

No; the CPU is not used to wait for this I/O operation. The thread pool thread is placed into a blocked state and swapped out of the CPU.

I call this "fake async" because it's a method that *appears* asynchronous but in reality is just blocking a thread pool thread.

> What is the different between really async function and this wrapper?

I explain this in full on my blog, but the core of it is that [pure async operations do not require a thread to be blocked](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> How can I know if the function that I use on C# is really async function until the kernel?

You can't; you need to know its implementation.

There are certain scenarios where you can deduce whether it is truly async. For example, the Win32 subsystem *does not allow* asynchronous file opens or deletions, so you can deduce that any "asynchronous" file open or delete operation is not truly asynchronous.

Comment: so when i wrap the delete i stack thread from the ThreaPool but this thread will not get a CPU time untill the delete will end?
so the only disadvantage (from pure async function)  is that now i have 1 less free thread on ThreadPool? the time will be same from pure async  and wrap async function ?

2- you said that i dont know if the function is pure async, but why? i can see if the procesess will open a new thread for it or no (according to 1)
because if it pure function i will not use on another thread .
thanks!

Comment: @FADI1987: There's some CPU time used to grab a thread from the thread pool and to return it when the delete is done. The thread pool will adjust itself if necessary. During the delete, your app will be using one more thread than it otherwise would. You can tell if an async method is truly async *if you can see its implementation*.

Comment: for summary:  
when i use pure async function i will not take any another thread, and my thread will get notify when the async function wil end
if i wrap function with Task.Run i will take thread from ThreadPool, and this thread dont do nothing
the only CPU time that i wast on this wrap is :take and release this thread 
but while the system will delete the file i will not wast any cpu time.

can i limit the number of thread that i use from the thread pool?
if i want to use on this wrap function with async await on many files, 
and if i dont do await on this function what will happen?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your first sentence. Most of the time you don't have to worry about limiting thread pool threads - the pool will adjust on its own. If you don't await the task, then you won't know when it completes or if it completed successfully.

Comment: ok
but , all what i wrote on last comment is true?
when i wrap on task.run the only disadvantage is the  time i loose when i take and release the thread?(and i thread on thread pool is blocking)

the thread itself that do the delete not take cpu time? it only stay on background and listen when the delete will end and notify my thread?

and if i use pure async i earn this time(take and release the thread)

Comment: There are other disadvantages: it takes time for the thread pool to recover; each additional thread takes up more memory, etc. It will stay on the thread pool thread, yes, and the `Task` completes when it's done, notifying the rest of your code. Using pure async avoids the disadvantages but that's not possible in this specific example.

Comment: ok now i get everything..i will be happy if you answer on the next question now.     i want to build a process that move on list  of folder and delete all the files that over then X KB....
what is the faster way do do this? if i use on the wrapper delete on each file that wast so much thread from threadpool and it take time and i thing that not logical because the i/o can't delete 2 file on same time  , do you have any idea?    i dont want to know on the foreach when the delete is completes  or if it compele successfully (i can write a log on the wrap function)  thanks!!!

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945193/what-is-better-way-to-delete-file-with-condition