# What is better way to delete file with condition

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, parallel-processing, delete-file

I want to build a win service(no UI) on c# that all what it done is: run on list of directories and delete files that over then X kb.
I want the better performance,

what is the better way to do this?
there is no pure async function for delete file so if i want to use async await 
I can wrap this function like:

```
public static class FileExtensions {
   public static Task DeleteAsync(this FileInfo fi) {
      return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fi.Delete() );
   }
}
```

and call to this function like:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
await fi.DeleteAsync();
```

i think to run like

```
foreach file on ListOfDirectories
{

  if(file.Length>1000)
      await file.DeleteAsync

}
```

but on this option the files will delete 1 by 1 (and every DeleteAsync will use on thread from the threadPool).
so i not earn from the async, i can do it 1 by 1.

maybe i think to collect X files on list and then delete them AsParallel

please help me to find the better way

Comment: First thing to optimize would be to filter on `.Length` *before* iterating.

Comment: as Filburt already said, first get all files into a list that meet the condition, then use `Parallel.ForEach` with your delete method. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) has an example

Comment: @MongZhu
why?
doyou want i will over on all the files and put on ListForDelete and then run again and delete all files from the list?
i don't get what you said and why

Comment: @Filburt foreach file on List.Where(f=>f.Length>1000) why that better? that will be same...

Comment: you could also put your condition into the the delete method, and still use Parallel.Foreach. Why reinvent the wheel ? There is already a `File.Delete` method

Comment: on File.Delete my thread was block while the delete happen

Comment: when I stop the time that it takes to delete more than 50 files, it seems that a normal for loop is faster than the parallel approach... You should try and measure the time

Comment: @MongZhu you tried to delete `foreach file in List {file.delete;}` and that faster then `Parallel.ForEach`...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles("DirectoryPath").Where(x=> new FileInfo(x).Length < 1000);` to get a list of files that are under 1 KB of size.

Then use Parallel.ForEach to iterate over that collection like this:

```
var collectionOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("DirectoryPath")
                                 .Where(x=> new FileInfo(x).Length < 1000);

Parallel.ForEach(collectionOfFiles, File.Delete);
```

It could be argued that you should use:

```
Parallel.ForEach(collectionOfFiles, currentFile =>
{
    File.Delete(currentFile);
});
```

to improve the readability of the code.

MSDN has a simple example on how to use [Parallel.ForEach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are wondering about the FileInfo object, here is [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You need to increase `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, because default one is too low for this (IO-bound) task.

Comment: @Evk Parallel.ForEach "send" every  delete to another thread on another code?
that not wast time to take and release thread every time?

and the defualt is not the number of core i have? why do i need to increase that

Comment: @FADI1987 I don't think it will send every item to new thread pool thread. Most likely it will partition your items into batches then will run them on X threads. But you want to increase number of threads because what you do is IO-bound. By default number of threads will be number of cores and that is fine when work is CPU-bound (some number crunching). In your case you can get better performance if you have more threads than CPU cores, because most threads will just be in a blocked state waiting for your delete to complete, and will do no work.

Comment: @Evk
and why dont wrap the delete with async await?
why this not give me better performance ...
by the way how do you know that this separate for group and send each group to another thread?

Comment: @FADI1987 Well I had to look at source code for Parallel.ForEach to verify that. Maybe it is listed somewhere in documentation, not sure. As for async\await you know that already - it will grab new thread from thread pool every time and you said yourself that this is crazy to do that for each delete.

Comment: @Evk
how can i see the source code of Parallel.ForEach? it interesting to see how it separate to group and send to thread, how much it put on each group, i want to see,
bt the way, it send to each thread group of file to delete, and that thread block and  don't do nothing because it's i/o bound
so why not give   on MaxDegreeOfParallelism 100 thread?

Comment: @FADI1987 Here is the source for parallel.ForEach: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,ac7837c53550ea6f. As for MaxDegreeOfParallelism - that is what I told you above - because it's IO bound you want to increase number of threads over default number. Note that it's still not that simple, because creating new threads in thread pool happens with a significant delay by default. You can remove that delay by setting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Evk
so you tell to set when start the program increase the min thread on threadpool that when i use  `Parallel.ForEach` (that take from threadPool) it not need to create a new thread?
so need `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`==`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` ?
so now if i put MaxDegreeOfParallelism 8 and i have 4 core it not need to create new thread on `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: @FADI1987 I cannot discuss that any more in comments, since that is not what comments are for. But basically yes, but only if you want to achieve max perfomance, and even then I'm not sure it will be faster. That depends on how fast HDD can perform that deletes, maybe you will achieve no gains from parallelisation. If I were you - I would just delete with one thread, maybe couple of them, unless the whole purpose of your application is to delete files fast. If that is the case - I would measure perfomance of different number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

this is may be can help you.

```
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static Task<int> DeleteAsync(this IEnumerable<FileInfo> files)
    {
        var count = files.Count();
        Parallel.ForEach(files, (f) =>
        {
            f.Delete();
        });
        return Task.FromResult(count);
    }
    public static async Task<int> DeleteAsync(this DirectoryInfo directory, Func<FileInfo, bool> predicate)
    {
        return await directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(predicate).DeleteAsync();
    }
    public static async Task<int> DeleteAsync(this IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, Func<FileInfo, bool> predicate)
    {
        return await files.Where(predicate).DeleteAsync();
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

```
        var _byte = 1;
        var _kb = _byte * 1000;
        var _mb = _kb * 1000;
        var _gb = _mb * 1000;
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\testDirectory");

        var deletedFileCount = await d.DeleteAsync(f => f.Length > _mb * 1);
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} Files larger than 1 megabyte deleted", deletedFileCount);
        // => 7 Files larger than 1 megabyte deleted

        deletedFileCount = await d.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(f => f.Length > _kb * 10).DeleteAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine("{0} Files larger than 10 kilobytes deleted", deletedFileCount);
        // => 11 Files larger than 10 kilobytes deleted
```